# Reversing a string with terminating punctuation results in errors

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am tyring to reverse a string in javascript with the following code.

```
const reverseString = str => [...str].sort(() => 1).join('');
```

All my test are passing, except the one in which the string contains punctuations at the end. *e.g* `hungry!`, `sharpshooter^`. What is causing the error?

### Test results

```
Input:    "I am hungry!"
Expected: "!yrgnuh ma I"
Received: "u!Iyrgn h ma"

Input:    "sharpshooter^"
Expected: "^retoohsprahs"
Received: "h^osaretorhsp"
```

Comment: Why are you `.sort()`ing? What is that intended to do? (regardless, it's resulting in undefined behavior)

Answer (score 2):

I guess its because position in ASCII table, why wouldn't you use `reverse()` ?

```
const reverseString = str => [...str].reverse().join('')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reverse()` to reverse the array before joining the array elements.

```js
function reverseString(str){
  return [...str].reverse().join('');
}

console.log(reverseString("I am hungry!"));
console.log(reverseString("sharpshooter^"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`const reverseString = str => [...str].sort(() => -1).join('');`

or even better...

`const reverseString = str => [...str].reverse().join('');`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use split reverse and join, use a simple loop

```js
function reverseString(str){
  let length = str.length
  let final = ''
  while(length-- > 0){
    final+= str[length]
  }
  return final
}

console.log(reverseString("I am hungry!"));
console.log(reverseString("sharpshooter^"));
```